# Best practices for naming "State" field

Tags: sql, sql-server, naming-conventions

When a U.S. address is stored, obviously it needs to have the state stored as well. The issue is that the word "State" is a reserved keyword in SQL.

What else should this be named? Are there any alternatives or do people just deal with having to wrap it in square braces?

Comment: It is actually a future keyword is fine for now.  Given the prevalence of `state` as a column name, I'm surprised Microsoft is even thinking of doing such a thing.

Comment: It just is bothersome since it is highlighted as if it is a reserved keyword in all the queries. I guess it isn't necessarily a problem then if that is the case.

Comment: You might consider using `state_code` or `state_abbrev` or something like that.

Comment: How about `state_id`, `state_code`, or `state_name`?

Comment: I suggest one avoid using a single noun as a column name and instead append a class word similar to the convention @TheImpaler suggested. That will help avoid conflicts with reserved keywords, current and future.

Answer (score 2):

Personally we prefer to use State as the property name and wrap it in queries or anywhere else there may be reserved word conflicts.  We have not had any issues with this in the 3 years I have been on the team.  Hope that helps!